# Windows 10 internal drive works fine but not showing in explorer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-explorer

**Running Windows 10, internal drives not showing up in Windows Explorer.**

(This is NOT the problem where a drive letter simply needs to be assigned to a new drive)

I have full access to my C: and F: drives. I can boot the machine, read and write files, there are no problems there.

To see the contents of C:, I put C:\ in the Windows Explorer bar.
I can access all the files and drives from a command prompt too.

**THE PROBLEM:**
There are no drives displayed at all in the "This PC" view. "This PC" is not listed in Explorer at all, but I can navigate there by backing up after putting "C:" into Explorer.

I used to see "This PC" and click on it to show the attached C, F and DVD drives. This was the usual way to see your disk drives.

Now it displays nothing, as if there are no drives in the PC, except I know they are there and all the other apps and software are working fine.

I should come clean at this point and explain that I had a disaster where I had to re-partition and reformat the drives, so the system has been messed around with. I did not keep a detailed log of the changes I made.

Right now the system is working flawlessly, it just has the one problem where it does not show the drives in Explorer, although you can go to "C:" or "F:" etc.

I used diskmgmt.msc and it can see all the drives and partitions. But explorer can't see any.

Can anyone help with some advice?

Researching this is tough because any reference to "This PC" turns up a lot of noise. I did find some registry keys that showed the long IDs for C: and F:, but Explorer does not want to display them.

I tried unplugging the F drive (leaving only C:) and rebooting and swapping to different SATA ports, but it is still the same or does not boot when not plugged in channel 0.

If I put C:\ into Windows Explorer, it displays all the files perfectly, but go up a level to "This PC" and nothing is found there.

I think the issue might be around Win 10 thinking my one big C partition is a boot partition (meant to be invisible) but all my user files are in there too, in the one big boot and data partition on C: .
[Disk Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1er5.png)

Comment: A screenshot of what you see when selecting "This PC" might be helpful.

Comment: The icon for "This pc" did not appear in explorer. The only way to get to a drive was by entering C: or F:\ in explorer. But I have reinstalled now.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Try the following - often helps here.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:

dism.exe   /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Complete, restart and test.

**(2)** If the above fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and start with Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

**(3)** Finally, it could be a bad (damaged) Windows User Profile. Try your test in a different Windows User Name.

Test 3 trumps 1 and 2.

**(4)** Then if everything above fails to produce results, back everything up and re-install Windows fresh, re-install Apps, and restore your data. Also (from Media Creation Link) Repair with Keep Nothing is very similar to fresh install.

Comment: For (3) I created a new admin user, logged in as them, but sadly still the same. (2) reinstalled Win10 with keep apps & files options, using a download from MS, incredibly the problem persists.  For (1) I ran all three utilities, all gave successful messages. I am confused how this could persist after a Windows reinstall. Thank you for your detailed replies, maybe a complete Win10 reinstall (without keep files option) might be the only way. Also tried uninstalling drives in device manager, checking event viewer (some DCOM messages?), uninstalled packages which might hook in to Explorer.

Comment: At this point (and I amended my answer), you now need to back everything up and re-install Windows. That is the only approach given everything else that was tried.  You can also use the Media Creation Link to reinstall Windows and use Keep Nothing.

Comment: Thanks John. I did this (back up then keep nothing option) and it's now all working beautifully, partitions, drive letters, starting up all good.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully then, you will acknowledge my answer above

Comment: I have upvoted/clicked the upper triangle, assuming this is the Acknowledge? If not let me know! Otherwise it is all running beautifully now after the restore, thanks for your advice, it worked a treat.